# Change of Voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> He slept on the floor.

Can the above sentence be changed to passive voice?
Or is it possible to change the voice at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

“The floor was slept on by him.”

It is helpful to appreciate the use of the passive in a fuller example with a wider context such as:

“He slept on the nursery floor when it was carpeted”.

In this case the passive construction would be

“The nursery floor was slept on by him when it was carpeted”

In this example, “when it was carpeted” is a restrictive clause that qualifies the circumstances in which the floor was slept on.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only transitive verbs can form the passive.